# Batch passive cluster node Win2012R2

Tags: batch-file, cluster-computing, findstr

I am trying to build a batch script which uses the cluster utility to define a VARIABLE1.

First IF has a perfect result - if the COMPUTERNAME is not listed in the list the VARIABLE1 is set.

The Problem is if the ERRORLEVEL = 0. Then it should find Strings beginning with "WINSV" and exclude the %COMPUTERNAME%

```
cluster node | findstr /r "WINSV*" | findstr /v "%COMPUTERNAME%"
```

Returns following:

```
WINSV9999         1 Up
```

The "cluster node" command returns:

```
    Node           Node ID Status
-------------- ------- ---------------------
WINSV9999         1 Up
WINSV9998         2 Up
```

The only thing that is missing now is how to print only the first 8 characters into the VARIABLE1 variable.
Any clue what is missing there? Thank you for the help.

```
    set CLUSTERGROUP=CLUSTERNAME
cluster group | find /I "%CLUSTERGROUP%" | find /I "%COMPUTERNAME%" 1>nul 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 (
    set VARIABLE1=%COMPUTERNAME%
) 
else ( 
cluster node | findstr /r "WINSV*" | findstr /v "%COMPUTERNAME%" 
)
```

Edit: 
Working now with this one:

```
set CLUSTERGROUP=CLUSTERNAME
call cluster group | find /I "%CLUSTERGROUP%" | find /I "%COMPUTERNAME%" 1>nul 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 (
    set VARIABLE1=%COMPUTERNAME%
) else (
    for /F "tokens=1" %%I in ('call cluster node ^| findstr /r "WINSV*" ^| findstr /v "\<%COMPUTERNAME%\>"') do set "VARIABLE1=%%I"
)
```

Now another problem, as I have other errorlevels in other scripts, the first line is not working. How do I remodel it - output to VARIABLE1 should be the %COMPUTERNAME% if the Node name (value WINSV9999 in the line starting with CLUSTERNAME) does not match the %COMPUTERNAME%. Any help on that? Thanks!

```
c:>cluster group
Listing status for all available resource groups:

Group                Node            Status
-------------------- --------------- ------
Available Storage    WINSV9999    Offline
Cluster Group        WINSV9999    Online
CLUSTERNAME          WINSV9999    Online
```

Comment: You need to capture the output of the `cluster` command into a variable by using a `FOR /F` command.  Then you can manipulate that variable.

Comment: What about this: `for /F "tokens=1" %%I in ('cluster node ^| findstr /I /B "\<%COMPUTERNAME%\>"') do set "VARIABLE1=%%I"`?

Comment: Note that `findstr /R "WINSV*"` is wrong: 1. to match a string beginning with `WINSV` use search string `"WINSV.*"` (`.*` meaning zero or more instances `*` of the preceding expression which is an arbitrary character `.`; you have defined zero or more instances of `V`), and 2. the `/R` is useless in pipes as there is no path specified...

Comment: Script is working now (see edit). However I need to remodel it because of the ERRORLEVEL. Any clues on that? Thank you!